# Very slow intellisense for CMake-configured Vulkan-project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, intellisense

I have a Vulkan project configured with the following CMakeLists.txt on Windows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(Custom_Vulkan)

set(MINGW_INCLUDE "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include")
find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED HINTS "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\cmake")

add_subdirectory(shaders)
add_executable(AppTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(AppTest PUBLIC Vulkan::Vulkan glfw)
include_directories(${MINGW_INCLUDE})
```

Extensions for CMake (CMake & CMake Tools), and C++ (C/C++, C/C++ Extension Pack, C/C++ Themes) are installed, and I have configured and built my executable using the CMake Tools-extension.

Intellisense can at times be unreasonably slow and freezes completely, resulting in 0 autocompletion suggestions for both constants from built-in libraries like `M_PI` from cmath, but also for the Vulkan/GLFW-APIs which have been located by CMake.

Where should I search in order to locate the dependency that stalls Intellisense?

Is it possible to monitor/profile the Intellisense-search in order to find the issue?

The CMake-tools project is fully able to detect the dependencies, and compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Intellisense-freezes were in this case caused by dependency-issues between a `FetchContent` repository dependency in CMake and the C# vscode extension pack which caused an OmniSharp server-handle to remain open.

This was a standard FetchContent-pull:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
    imgui_repo
    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/ocornut/imgui.git"
)


FetchContent_MakeAvailable(imgui_repo)
```

Right-clicking the extension followed by `disable(workspace)` solved the issue.